# jQuery ajax request inside fade callback executing multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback, fadeout

This is how my HTML looks:

```
    <ul id="list">
            <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
    <ul>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
    $("#list li").fadeOut(600, function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/functions/ajax.php",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "json",
            })
        .done(function(data){
            otherFunction(data);
        });         
    });
```

So, I'm trying to hide the list elements and after that run the ajax request. But the problem is that for some reason the ajax request is executing three times. If I remove the fade function the request executes properly (only once), so probably is running as many times as items are on my list, which I find strange. Is that possible? Can you help me to figure out a solution? I really need that ajax request to execute only when the fadeOut function has finished.

I hope I made myself clear and I apologize if I messed up with my english.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard animation `complete` callback is called for each element in the collection.

If you use [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) you can queue a callback that will wait until *all* animations have completed on the given collection:

```
$('#myList li').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    console.log('per element');
}).promise().done(function() {
    console.log('all elements');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/cLv8X/

Comment: Nice one, did not even know that ;)

Comment: Nice! that's new to me also. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you selector is referencing 3 elements, so the callback is executed three times (one for each element fading out) Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/55XTq/) to see this

```
<ul>
  <li>One
  <li>Two
  <li>Three
<script>
 $('li').fadeOut(600, function() {
   console.log('Faded');
 });
</script>
```

You could try and call fadeout on the whole list like so:

```
$("#list")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that it gets executed 3 times since it will call the `fade-out` handler for each `li` that has been faded out. What you could do is keep track of how many `li` has to be faded and once they are all fadedout, make your ajax call.

```
var $listEls = $("#list li"),
    listElsCount = $listEls.length,
    fadedListElsCount = 0;

$listEls.fadeOut(600, function(){
    if (++fadedListElsCount !== listElsCount) {
         return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/functions/ajax.php",
        data: { id: id },
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function(data){
        otherFunction(data);
    });         
});
```

You could also simply fade-out the whole list.

```
$("#list").fadeOut(600, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good way to patch it to only run once with multiple jQuery calls

```
$('#1stID, #2ndID').fadeOut(350).promise().done(() => {
   //Do your thing that you only want to run once.
});
```